# How can Avoid Oracle Ref Cursor

Tags: oracle

i have a develop a application that contain large no of rows i was using ref cursor but i do not need a cursor. how can achieve that.

```
here is below code i was using ref cursor please help me out how can avoid it.any idea

create or replace
PROCEDURE remove_emp 
(
employee_id in NUMBER,
o_data out sys_refcursor
) 
AS
        v_account_status        help.topic%type;
        v_username             help.seq%type;
        v_lock_date             help.info%type;        
BEGIN
         open o_data for
         select topic,seq, info
         into  v_account_status,v_username,v_lock_date
         from help;-- where seq=employee_id ;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('topic:'||v_account_status);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('seq:'||v_username);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('info:'||v_lock_date);
   END remove_emp;
```

Comment: You can either dump all the data to any table and use it from that in your application directly or either connect to Oracle DB from your application and query main tables directly.

Comment: can u provide simple code how can dump it actually i was new in oracle i was working on two days before please help me figure out how can dump it.

Comment: dump  table means create temp table or another

Comment: Always tell us what you want rather than asking us what you don't want or how to avoid something.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the cursor and just use `SELECT ... INTO ...`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE help ( topic, seq, info ) AS
  SELECT 'a', 1, 'aa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 2, 'bb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 3, 'cc' FROM DUAL;
```

**Procedure**:

```sql
create PROCEDURE remove_emp 
(
  employee_id in help.seq%type
) 
AS
  v_account_status help.topic%type;
  v_username       help.seq%type;
  v_lock_date      help.info%type;        
BEGIN
  select topic,seq, info
  into  v_account_status,v_username,v_lock_date
  from help where seq=employee_id;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('topic:'||v_account_status);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('seq:'||v_username);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('info:'||v_lock_date);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('seq:Not Found!');
END remove_emp;
/
```

**Call the procedure**:

```sql
BEGIN
  remove_emp(1);
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
topic:a
seq:1
info:aa
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2af471ad61f77c4c3ba81fac0fffe0d7)*

Comment: @SantoshKumarBind That is the full code. If it is not what you are after then you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56885381/edit) your question and make it clearer exactly what you are expecting.

Comment: Maybe the missing bit is handling no_data_found exceptions.

Comment: @Rene Added as its good practice but it's not really within the scope of the "how to do this without a ref cursor" question. Mostly just waiting for the OP to clarify what they are expecting from an answer.

Comment: Given the name of the procedure maybe the removal of the emp record. Who knows...